# How to stop else condition execution repeatedly in java

Tags: java

The `else`-condition checks every value in my code, but I want it to only execute once; that's enough.`if` condition working fine by using Boolean value.
in `else`-condition how to use.

Here my code:

```
Session session = null;
try{
Query qu = session.createSQLQuery("select plot_no from house_details where type='duplex'");
List<Long> li =  qu.list();
System.out.println("---li---"+li.toString());
boolean enteredIf = true;
for (Iterator itr = li.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
    String plotNo = itr.next().toString();
     if(enteredIf)
    if(plotNo.equals("501") || plotNo.equals("520") || plotNo.equals("601"){
        System.out.println("---if---");
        enteredIf=false;
        //code here
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("---else---");
        Query qu1 = session.createSQLQuery("select distinct name, houseno from house_details");
        List li1 =  qu1.list();
        for (Iterator itr1 = li.iterator(); itr1.hasNext();) {
            Object[] obj = (Object[]) itr1.next();
            String houseName = (String) obj[0];
            String houseNo = (String) obj[1];
            System.out.println("---houseName--->"+houseName);
        }
    }
}
} catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
if(session != null){
    session.close();
}
}
```

**Output:**

```
---li---[501, 501, 0, 101, 520,601,601, 101, 114,102,103,104]
```

in my output so many values is there, so many times **else** condition checking,i want only one time excecution

Comment: use an elseif instead

Answer (score 0):

Use `continue` to re-iterate the loop without jumping into `else` parts or above the line where you don't want the rest of the lines to be executed in this iteration.

**Note :** You can use `break;` as well to jump out from the loop iterations.

See the [usage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

Comment: @Sri Have you been clear of using `continue` and `break` as per the need ?

Comment: Cant you break the loop instead of setting `enteredIf=false;`

Comment: i use only 'continue'

Comment: @Sri Re-format your codes, Where is else part of `if(enteredIf)` and what is the actual purpose of `enteredIf=false;` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110823/discussion-between-sri-and-shree-krishna).